# How to replace .click with auto function

Tags: jquery, css, replace, parent

This function will replace parent .wmessage div css with .v-boxinner div css.

The problem now is that this function start on click. What I need is to replace click function with avto start.

```
$(".wmessage").parent().click(function(){
    var array = ['width'];
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each( array , function(item, value) {
        $(".v-boxinner").css(value, $this.css(value));
    });
});
```

This is what I was looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var properties = ["width"];
var src = $(".wmessage").parent();
$.each( properties , function(item, value) {
    $(".v-boxinner").css(value, src.css(value));
});
```

});

Thank you @BeNdErR

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's unclear totally.

Comment: I think you're needing to use trigger() ???

Comment: I have tried and it's not working. I have also update question. @BhojendraNepal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the function automatically when the page loads you have to call it once the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //--- do what you need here
});
```

Here's an example, edit it to suit your needs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var properties = ["background", "width"];
    var src = $("#copyme");
    $.each( properties , function(item, value) {
        $("#target").css(value, src.css(value));
    });
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s00kpL1b/

Comment: I replaced .click with .ready and it's not working.

Comment: you don't have to replace click with ready. ready is bound to document. rephrase your script to work after the dom is ready

Comment: If I would know how to do this I would already do it. I put this code together from 2 other posts, now I don't know how to complete it.

Comment: I only had to replace "var src = $("#copyme");" with "var src = $("#copyme").parent();" Now is working perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if autostart means when someone starts changing the message or when the page loads. If first option:

```
$(".wmessage").parent().change(function(){
    var array = ['width'];
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each( array , function(item, value) {
        $(".v-boxinner").css(value, $this.css(value));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need a self-executing function

```
(function YourFunctionName(){ 
//do something 
})();
```

or anonymous

```
(function(){ 
//do something 
})();
```

this function will run automatically